# Crystal Reports 6.0 Error Code 997

Tags: crystal-reports, error-code

Can anyone describe "Crystal Report Engine Returns Error Code 997" for Crystal Reports 6.0?
Googling proved futile.

Comment: heh. I googled 'Crystal Report Error Code 997' and the 2nd result was this page.  The 1st result didn't give an answer since Experts-Exchange no longers displays the solutions.

Comment: @PowerUser -- really?  If you scroll all the way to the bottom, they should still be there, at least for Google searches.

Comment: you don't happen to be using bar code fonts in the reports, do you?

Comment: no barcode fonts here, just a printing a simple report. This works on Test oracle environment, only difference between test and production is data as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, I think i might have found a possible reason for this error
[See Here][1]


  [1]: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=887470

Basically this seems to be an oracle error that has bubbled up to the crystal report. Since it was not handled in crystal reports, it just spat it out as is. Can anyone verify this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a `long` datatype in the data source?

If your theory is right, and if you have the `long` datatype in either a `CONNECT BY`, `GROUP BY`, or `ORDER BY` clause, that could be the culprit.  From what I have read, the ORA-00997 error is as follows:

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype:
>
> Cause: A value of datatype LONG was used in a function or in a DISTINCT, WHERE, CONNECT BY, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause. A LONG value can only be used in a SELECT clause.

I have seen Crystal Reports bubble up unhandled SQL Server errors before, so it's possible.